# using Macros in c

Tags: c

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
int aarray[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
#define SIZE (sizeof(aarray)/sizeof(int))

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",SIZE);
    if(-1<=SIZE)printf("1\n");
    else printf("2\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this prints 2? The SIZE is 8 which is greater than -1 so it should have printed 1. But why is it printing 2? Please help me understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing a signed value (`-1`) and an unsigned value (the value produced by `SIZE` is `size_t` which is unsigned).

Thus `-1` is promoted to an unsigned and becomes larger than `SIZE`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in type promotion in your favorite C book. The result of sizeof is unsigned, and then -1 gets transformed to unsigned, which is a big number.